# Можно ли сократить данную запись

Tags: c#

Перешёл с Java на C# и сейчас решил кратко ознакомиться с местным похожим синтаксисом. Хотел поинтересоваться, можно ли как-то сократить данную запись кода?

```
    double res = summ( Convert.ToDouble( Console.ReadLine() ), Convert.ToDouble( Console.ReadLine() ) );
    Console.WriteLine( res );
```

Сразу прошу не ругать за код. Если есть какие-то подсказки по написанию, как начинающему, буду рад их почитать.

```
    public static double summ( double a, double b )
    {
        double res = a + b;
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: можешь вынести получение числа из консоли в функцию

Comment: Для начала - код надо постить текстом. Для продолжения - прочитать описание метки [инспекция-кода].

Comment: можно сократить метод `summ` с помощью лямбды: `public static double summ(double a, double b) => a + b`

Answer (score 1):

```
double a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
double b = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
double res = a + b;
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

- Название методов согласованно писать с большой буквы